# Rename files with different extensions via Windows batch

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop, file-rename

I've spent two days on this and have looked at most every forum file I can find. Here's the scenario:

I have tens of thousands of image files: img_123.jpg, img_124.cr2, img_125.mov, etc. and I need them named: 64,001.jpg  64,002.cr2  64,003.mov and so on. Basically renaming the file while keeping the original extension in tact, while putting a comma in the thousands position.

Thanks to reading through the helpful Q&A's on Stack Overflow, I was able to write something that either A) renames the files serially but with no comma (64001.jpg 64002.cr2 64003.mov, etc.); or B) renames only the very first file for a unique type (img_123.jpg becomes 64,001.jpg just fine, while img_124.jpg img_125.jpg, etc. each fail with an error saying the filename is not unique.

Here's my code:

Comment: Using comma in file names might be a bad idea, as it's not a valid character for the short (8.3) name in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I hear ya. Is there anything in my code that sends a red flag in terms of upping the "counter" by one? I don't know a lot, but I think the SET /A is for numerical values only.

Comment: Magoo: You ROCK man! I fixed the bits that caused it to act on every file in the directory but you fixed the larger rename problem and for that I'm grateful!!!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET /a num=64000
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF !num! lss 1000000 (
  SET "newname=!num:~0,-3!,!num:~-3!"
 ) ELSE (
  SET "newname=!num:~0,-6!,!num:~-6,3!,!num:~-3!"
 )
 ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!newname!%%~xa"
 SET /a num+=1
)

GOTO :EOF
```

All you'd need to do is set up `sourcedir` to suit your system.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Wow! You're a GENIUS!! It renamed everything in the folder, though. which isn't okay but maybe I can fix this by altering line #6 (where the dir qualification is). to say

Comment: Here's the code that worked:  @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=G:\ch\dos batch tests\# Projects\see if you can insert a coma"
SET /p num=enter the next higher number here:  
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir *.jpg *.cr2 *.mov /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg *.cr2 *.mov" '
 ) DO (
 IF !num! lss 1000000 (
  SET "newname=!num:~0,-3!,!num:~-3!"
 ) ELSE (
  SET "newname=!num:~0,-6!,!num:~-6,3!,!num:~-3!"
 )
 REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!newname!%%~xa"
 SET /a num+=1
)

GOTO :EOF

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked, thanks to Magoo for coming up with 95% of this.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=G:\ch\dos batch tests\# Projects\see if you can insert a coma"
SET /p num=enter the next higher image number here:  
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir *.jpg *.cr2 *.mov /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg *.cr2 *.mov" '
 ) DO (
 IF !num! lss 1000000 (
  SET "newname=!num:~0,-3!,!num:~-3!"
 ) ELSE (

  SET "newname=!num:~0,-6!,!num:~-6,3!,!num:~-3!"
 )
 REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!newname!%%~xa"
 SET /a num+=1
)

GOTO :EOF
```